# Alcohol when flying to Singapore from EU through Malaysia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore, connecting-flights, malaysia, alcohol

We plan to fly from an EU country to Singapore with transit in Kuala Lumpur. This is one ticket, yet it's two different airlines, so we will change airplanes in Kuala Lumpur.

I have read that certain allowances for alcohol when entering Singapore do not apply if you arrive from Malaysia.

Now I wonder if the transit in Kuala Lumpur would technically make us "arrive from Malaysia" or if from the view of customs, our luggage will be checked through and it will arrive in Singapore "from the EU".

Also I was unable to find out what amount of alcohol one would be allowed to bring tax-free into Singapore when entering from Malaysia.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are only in transit in Malaysia and your luggage is checked through, meaning it has never entered Malaysia, from Singapore's point of view **you are coming from the EU, not Malaysia**.  Your boarding passes and the tag on your luggage will make this clear.

This is a good thing, since if you *were* coming from Malaysia, your alcohol allowance would be zero:

> There is no duty-free concession on liquor products for people arriving from Malaysia.

https://www.customs.gov.sg/individuals/going-through-customs/arrival/duty-free-concession-and-gst-relief